# Meaning of "Aufgeplatzte Beeren und die Kirschessigfliege sind bei den Winzern in aller Munde."

Tags: meaning

From the *Hohlspiegel* column of Der Spiegel, which is intended for funny/interesting sentences from other sources:

> Aus der *Rheinzeitung*:
>
> Frühburgunder, Portugieser und die Rebsorte Ortega werden bereits seit Tagen gelesen. Aufgeplatzte Beeren und die Kirschessigfliege sind dabei zurzeit bei den Winzern in aller Munde.

So, those three types of vines have been harvested since days. Bursted berries and the fly are now the topic on everyone's lips among the wine growers.

This seems normal to me. How is it funny/interesting?

Comment: Possibly the notion that the wine growers have *actual* flies and berries in their mouth, while they are doing the harvest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already did it right: [*In aller Munde sein*](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_aller_Munde_sein) translates as *to be in everyone's mouth* and is the german equivalent to *to be on everyone's lips*. It is a fix phrase meaning that something or someone is being talked about everywhere.

But just as you can understand *on everyone's lips* literally, you can read the given sentence in a way that the wine growers actually have flies in their mouth, which is quite disgusting, for sure.

Today, the dated phrase *in aller Munde* is frequently used to create humorous allusions and puns. For example, the website http://www.in-aller-munde.net/ leads to a candy manufactory.